# Is it possible that Kafka Streams have different context time in different nodes?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is `ProcessorContext#timestamp()` returns the time of the current node or a whole topology?

Is it possible that different nodes have different stream time?

For example if implementation of `ProcessorContext#schedule()` is differs from node to node.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like `ProcessorContext#timestamp()` returns the record timestamp, not the stream time.

It is possible for different nodes to have different stream times based on the records they've processed. Each node's stream time will only increase after processing another record, so each will have their own local view of stream time based on what they've processed.